# Find a class by a part of classname

Tags: javascript, jquery

i trie to get a full classname "i-need-this-2" from a part of known-classname "i-need-this-" of a element.

Example

```
<div id="myelement" class="firstclass i-need-this-2 anotherclass"></div>
```

I trie to get the complete classes of the element, make a array, and search with indexof for the wanted class, but my code failed.

```
partofclassname='i-need-this-';
let allclasses = $('#myelement').attr('class').split(' ');
let wanted_class= allclasses[allclasses.indexOf(partofclassname)];
```

wanted_class is undefined and indexof is -1

What is wrong with my code?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you tried `$('div[class*="i-need-this-"]')`

Comment: That dont return the complete classname, wich i trie to get

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is almost there. When you use `split` it will return an array. You can use `filter` function and in the callback use `includes` . So this array will have those classes which includes the keyword you are looking for

```js
let partofclassname = 'i-need-this-';
let matchedClass = $('#myelement').attr('class').split(' ').filter(item => item.includes(partofclassname));
console.log(matchedClass)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myelement" class="firstclass i-need-this-2 anotherclass"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`allclasses.indexOf(partofclassname)` will check for complete string(class). For part you need check each element of array.
Use [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)and check in each element of array using [`String.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

```js
partofclassname='i-need-this-';
let allclasses = $('#myelement').attr('class').split(' ');
console.log(allclasses)
let wanted_class = allclasses.find(c => c.indexOf(partofclassname) !== -1);
console.log(wanted_class)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myelement" class="firstclass i-need-this-2 anotherclass"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

With `RegExp` :

```js
var patt =/\bi-need-this-[^ ]*/g ;

let allclasses = document.getElementById('myelement').className ;

console.log( allclasses.match(patt)[0] ) ;
```

```html
<div id="myelement" class="firstclass i-need-this-2 anotherclass"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `indexOf` on the class name value instead of doing that in the array of those class name:

```js
let partofclassname='i-need-this-';
let allclasses = $('#myelement').attr('class').split(' ');
let index = allclasses.findIndex((className) => className.indexOf(partofclassname) !== -1);
let wanted_class= allclasses[index];
console.log(wanted_class);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myelement" class="firstclass i-need-this-2 anotherclass"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `indexOf` find **exact match** of elements.

try `filter` instead.

```js
let partofclassname = 'i-need-this-';
let allclasses = $('#myelement').attr('class').split(' ');
let wanted_class = allclasses.filter(e => e.includes(partofclassname));

console.log(wanted_class)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myelement" class="firstclass i-need-this-2 anotherclass"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve your desired classname.

- You could efficiently use [.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) along with [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) as follows -

```js
let allclasses = $('#myelement').attr('class').split(' ');
let partofclassname='i-need-this-';
let wanted_class = allclasses.find(element => element.includes(partofclassname));

console.log(wanted_class);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myelement" class="firstclass i-need-this-2 anotherclass"></div>
```

- You could simply do it using a loop & `includes` as follows -

```js
let allclasses = $('#myelement').attr('class').split(' ');
let partofclassname='i-need-this-';
let wanted_class = undefined;

allclasses.forEach(element => {
 wanted_class = element.includes(partofclassname) ? element : wanted_class
});

console.log(wanted_class)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myelement" class="firstclass i-need-this-2 anotherclass"></div>
```